# Launch a custom dialog when clicked on notification

Tags: android, android-dialog

I want to launch an custom dialog when user clicks on the notification in the notification bar.

I have already created the notification and the custom dialog class. But i do not know how to launch when user clicks it.

All tutorials i searched launch a Activity and not a dialog. So, can anyone help me with this regard.

Thank you.

This is my Custom Dialog code

```
public class custom_dialog extends Dialog {
    Context m_context;
    LayoutInflater mInflater = null;

    public custom_dialog (Context context, int theme) {
        super(context,R.style.Theme_Dialog);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        this.m_context = context;
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"onCreate", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        mInflater=LayoutInflater.from(m_context);
              }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }
}
```

Comment: it would be nice to see how you dialog class looks like, if you use fragment and instance (which you should) you call it using fragment manager

Comment: Set your activity's theme to dialog, e.g. `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"`

Comment: I have updated my question with the code.

Comment: I actually use my own theme for the custom dialog. Also is Theme.Dialog available for android 2.3 devices also?

Answer (score 2):

you can try with this code

```
Context context = getApplicationContext();
CharSequence contentTitle = "Title";
CharSequence contentText = "content";
Intent notifyIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse("http://www.android.com"));

PendingIntent intent = 
                PendingIntent.getActivity(SimpleNotification.this, 0, 
                notifyIntent, android.content.Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

notifyDetails.setLatestEventInfo(context, contentTitle, contentText, intent);
mNotificationManager.notify(SIMPLE_NOTFICATION_ID, notifyDetails);
```

just make the pendingintent open up one of your activities and have your activity be complete transparent and just open a dialog.

Comment: I actually use my own theme for the custom dialog. Also setLatestEventInfo is deprecated. So we should use Notification.Builder for it.

Comment: @Vinuthan We can use Notification.Builder for it. When you are calling activity set theme as transparent as well as your custom dialog theme to acitivity so it will show the appearance like dialog.

Comment: i will give it a try and get back to you. Thank you.

Comment: It is working, but my animations are not working.. How to set my animations for an activity?

Comment: you have animations in your custom dialog ? or somewhere in side ?

Comment: did you check whether your context is there ? means value of context nul or something else ?

Comment: Ya, i have animations in the dialog itself and now able to get those animations properly :) actually had changed the theme a bit so there was no proper animation, now it is fixed!

Answer (score 2):

Well any click is like a click on an element . I launch my custom dialog on click of a button. Here's how i do it :

main.xml :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonShowCustomDialog"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Show Custom Dialog" />

</LinearLayout>
```

custom.xml :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#FFF" 
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/image"/>/>

     <Button
        android:id="@+id/dialogButtonOK"
        android:layout_width="100px"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=" Ok "
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/image"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Now for the java to bind them :

MainActivity.java :

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    final Context context = this;
    private Button button;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonShowCustomDialog);

        // add button listener
        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

          @Override
          public void onClick(View arg0) {

            // custom dialog
            final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom);
            dialog.setTitle("Custom Title");

            // set the custom dialog components - text, image and button
            TextView text = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.text);
            text.setText("Android custom dialog example!");
            ImageView image = (ImageView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.image);
            image.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);

            Button dialogButton = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialogButtonOK);
            // if button is clicked, close the custom dialog
            dialogButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });

            dialog.show();
          }
        });
    }
}
```

You can probably leverage this for your purpose ...

Comment: I am sorry but i think you got it wrong, My question is how to launch an dialog when user clicks on the notification in the notification bar. Your solution launches on a button click.

Comment: @Vinuthan : Any click whether its on a button or a notification bar is a click event only. All you need to do here is catch the notification  from R.java, instead of button, say like this:
`nfBar= (nfBar)findViewById(R.id.buttonShowCustomDialog);` . Now you just need to set `nfBar.setOnClickListener()` instead of `button.setOnClickListener`.

Comment: Yes, that is what i am asking the question. How to launch an dialog from a notification click. I am already launching the dialog with a button click.

Comment: What about `notification.setOnClickListener()` ? Does that work ?